# Phone Gap Ajax fail on https

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, phonegap-build, phonegap-cli

I create rest api wchich contains only html+css+js files.
I have simple function login wchich get by json get data.
When i run this app on my server i'v got a ajax error : status Ready 0 , status 0 
But when i run this code on http on diffrent port its work correctly.
I check a random json files from internet with http and https urls: 
1. http - http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=1
2. https - https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos
And it's work correctly

Here my js function wchich called on button click on document ready :

```
function log_in() {


$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    async: true,
    crossDomain: true,
    /*url: "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=1",*/
    /*url: "https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos",*/ /*na debug i relese dziala*/
    url:"https://system.fastdata.com.pl:4567/apps/leadinfo/f/json.txt",
     /*url: "https://system.fastdata.com.pl:4569/apps/x/y/json.txt",*/
    data: {},

    beforeSend: load_start(),
    success: function (data) {
        window.test = data;
        console.log("autoryzowano");
        console.log(data);
        $("#login_error").append("tak", data[0]);
        $("#login_error").css("display", "block");
        $("#password").val('');
        $("#username").val('');
        $("#contact_info_load").remove();
    },
    error: function (xhr,err) {
        console.log("nie autoryzowano");

      $("#login_error").append("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status);
        $("#login_error").append("responseText: "+xhr.responseText);
        $("#login_error").css("display", "block");
        $("#password").val('');
        $("#username").val('');
        $("#contact_info_load").remove();
    }
});
```

}

and here my config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- config.xml reference: https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml -->
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id        = "Lead Info"
    version   = "1.0.0">

<name>LEADInfo</name>

<description>

</description>

<author >
    FASTDATA Team
</author>
<icon src="fa-cogs.png"   />
<!--
    If you do not want any permissions to be added to your app, add the
    following tag to your config.xml; you will still have the INTERNET
    permission on your app, which PhoneGap requires.
-->
<preference name='phonegap-version' value='cli-5.2.0' />
<!--<preference name='phonegap-version' value='cli-6.0.0' />-->
<preference name="android-build-tool" value="ant" />


<preference name="orientation"                value="default" />        <!-- all: default means both landscape and portrait are enabled -->
<preference name="target-device"              value="universal" />      <!-- all: possible values handset, tablet, or universal -->
<preference name="fullscreen"                 value="true" />           <!-- all: hides the status bar at the top of the screen -->
<preference name="webviewbounce"              value="true" />           <!-- ios: control whether the screen 'bounces' when scrolled beyond the top -->
<preference name="prerendered-icon"           value="true" />           <!-- ios: if icon is prerendered, iOS will not apply it's gloss to the app's icon on the user's home screen -->
<preference name="stay-in-webview"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: external links should open in the default browser, 'true' would use the webview the app lives in -->
<preference name="ios-statusbarstyle"         value="black-opaque" />   <!-- ios: black-translucent will appear black because the PhoneGap webview doesn't go beneath the status bar -->
<preference name="detect-data-types"          value="true" />           <!-- ios: controls whether data types (such as phone no. and dates) are automatically turned into links by the system -->
<preference name="exit-on-suspend"            value="false" />          <!-- ios: if set to true, app will terminate when home button is pressed -->
<preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the spinner won't appear on the splash screen during app loading -->
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen"    value="true" />           <!-- ios: if set to false, the splash screen must be hidden using a JavaScript API -->
<preference name="disable-cursor"             value="false" />          <!-- blackberry: prevents a mouse-icon/cursor from being displayed on the app -->
<preference name="android-installLocation"    value="auto" />           <!-- android: app install location. 'auto' will choose. 'internalOnly' is device memory. 'preferExternal' is SDCard. -->
<!--
    Define a specific version of PhoneGap to build into your app.
    <preference name="phonegap-version"       value="3.5.0" />
-->



<!-- Plugins -->

<!-- Core plugins -->
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" />



<!-- Define app splash screen for each platform. -->
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png"       gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png"       gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png"       gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png"      gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png"              gap:platform="blackberry" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png"         gap:platform="ios"     width="320" height="480" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png"      gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="960" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="1136" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png"           gap:platform="ios"     width="768" height="1024" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png"          gap:platform="ios"     width="1024" height="768" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg"      gap:platform="winphone" />


 <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" source="npm" />



<gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="CFBundleShortVersionString">
<string>100</string>
</gap:config-file>

<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm"/>
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" source="npm"/>
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" source="npm"/>
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm"/>

<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" source="npm"/>
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-admobpro" source="npm" spec="2.9.6"/>

<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm"/>
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
<allow-intent href="*"/>
<!--<access origin="*"/>-->
<access origin="*" subdomains="true" />
<access subdomains='true' origin='*' />
<!--<platform name="android">-->
    <!--<allow-intent href="market:*" />-->
<!--</platform>-->
<!--<platform name="ios">-->
    <!--<allow-intent href="itms:*" />-->
    <!--<allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />-->
<!--</platform>-->
```

Does anybody know whats is wron with my code ? Is that an ssl certyficate on server error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could maybe try it like this

```
<access origin = "*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
```

I'm not sure but maybe the global '*' could be on http only.